# How to dismiss keyboard before pushing UIViewController in navigationController

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitableview, uialertview

My view contains `UITableViewController` which has `UITextFields` where some text can be entered. I adjust `UITableView` height when keyboard appears/disappears. It works great.

Now I have `UIAlertView` with `UITextField` in it. User enters text in `UITextField` in `UIAlertView` & when Ok is pressed, I push another  `UIViewController`. The problem is when I come back to the view it's screwed. The reason is with `KeyboardWillHide` notification is never fired & hence the height of tableView is application frame height - keyboard height.

Any suggestions for fixing it? I called `[resignFirstResponder]`  in `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` but didn't help. I even forcefully called `KeyboardWillHide` but that also didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When this happens, is the keyboard still on the screen or is it solely a view size problem?

Comment: keyboard is gone. The problem is with the frame height which does not get adjusted back

Comment: But ideally you should not use UITextField inside your UIAlertView. UIAlertView is used to show any alert and take decision accordingly.Not to enter any text.

Comment: A couple of things to check: Presumably you call `removeObserver` at some point; is that happening before the keyboard goes away?  Do you see any difference if you call `endEditing` on the superview instead of `resignFirstResponder`?

Comment: changing to endEditing didn't help. I have solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was calling removerObserver in viewWillDisappear. viewWillDisappear was getting called before keyboardWillHide was getting called. 
The solution was move removeObserver to viewDidDisappear. That did the trick.

Comment: ok guys this added another problem in cases when new view contains keyboard. So I moved obeservers back to viewWillAppear/Disappear. Now I fix the table frame in viewWillAppear